# Can google maps layer be imported into tatukGis ViewerWnd

Tags: google-maps, delphi

I understand that google maps policy is pretty strict. I am using TatukGIS component with delphi XE3 and I would need to import google maps as raster base layer into Tatuk viewer window. Tatuk examples for OSM are pretty straight-forward and simple however only web tiles are a valid format. Is there any way to access Google maps as WMS (is access to google maps web tiles possible)?

Answer (score 0):

Direct access to google maps tiles is prohibited by the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

> 10.1 Administrative Restrictions.
>
> No access to APIs or Content except through the Service. You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).

Comment: I was aware of API only access. How about payable google services for direct tile access- is there such a thing? Is there maybe an option to make an agreement with digitalglobe?